# Using Litree in PDAL

Tags: pdal

I am trying to use the `filters.litree` to segment individual tree. It seems it requires an `HeightAboveGround` field which I make sure my las file has. But despite this fact, I still get this error message: `filters.litree: Missing HeightAboveGround dimension in input PointView.`

My pipeline is written as is:

```
tree_id = """[
"test.las",
{
    "type":"filters.litree",
    "min_points":50,
    "min_height":10.0,
    "radius":200.0
},
{
    "type":"writers.las",
    "filename":"tree_id.las",
    "minor_version":1.4,
    "extra_dims":"all"
}]"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading from a las-File, be sure to specify which dimensions should be **read**, by replacing the input file with a pipeline entry for `readers.las`:

```
...
{
     "type": "readers.las",
     "filename": "test.las",
     "extra_dims": "HeightAboveGround=float"
},
...
```

You can also try setting `use_eb_vlr` to `true` instead of specifying `extra_dims` manually.
For more options, see the documentation: https://pdal.io/stages/readers.las.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clarification on the readers. that works! couldn't edit your answer, but just commas missing after the first and second line.

Comment: thanks for the fix, added them :)

Comment: Just a heads up to other users of this tool, the tool now runs, but seems to run for ever. still haven't finished running on a pretty small subset after 2 days.

Comment: Another user encountered this issue of the long runtime and created an issue [here](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/3518). This will be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: Awesome thanks, you have a rough idea of when the new release should be?